# How to package python files without exposing source code

Tags: python, jar, jython, packaging

I am coding for a Secure Key Management module in python.

I don't want to package and expose my **.py** files which contains very important algorithms.

Is it possible to package **.pyc** files just like we create a **.jar** out of .class files in Java and be able to execute the functionalities?

I dont think I should switch to writing entire code in Java for this reason.

Jython is used for this purpose?

Comment: You can take a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5458048/how-to-make-a-python-script-standalone-executable-to-run-without-any-dependency)

Comment: A tip: `.pyc` file can be very easy *decompile*. Then user can get the source code.

Comment: @KevinGuan So that means I cannot use python for this usecase?

Comment: However I didn't say that you can't do this :). But since I also didn't try to do this, so I can't give you a solution :P

Comment: Also: secure key management does not come from closed source code, it comes from proper encryption and good, efffective policies.